# How to list packages to be removed by ubuntu-release-upgrader and how to prevent selected removals?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I have ubuntu 22.04 LTS

When I run

```
sudo apt update ; apt list --upgradable
```

these packges are listed + few others:

```
python3-distupgrade
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
```

How can I list with `apt` or other command line tools what packages these upgraders are going to remove?

If I run GUI System / Admin / Software updater it proposes "Partial update" which shows list of removed packages but the GUI is for some reason so limited that it is not possible to copy/paste information about packages to be removed as text.

From the GUI I can see that the updater(s) plans to remove several packages that I have manually installed, e.g. `vlc` and `keepassxc`. How is this possible because I thought that manually installed packages are not automatically removed in any case.

If I want to prevent the automatic removal for selected packages like `vlc` and `keepassxc` how can I do it?

Thank you for your help and support.

Comment: Never accept a partial upgrade. Especially a partial upgrade that removes applications that you want to keep. There are other questions today from folks who accepted a partial upgrade to their regret. You were very wise to read the proposed changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/2030262